# What is the state of the art for multiple identity management in GPG?

Tags: git, github, gnupg, sign

I created a pair of GPG keys to reflect my true identity and am now trying to create a solid reputation around it. My goal is to use a single GPG key (with subkeys) to cover all my online needs and keep it as generic as possible (I use gpg@example.com as my identity).

I've also been using a mail catchall for years to use one mail address per web site, to be able to filter, sort and find the origins of them automatically.

But I find it hard to make the link between the two. For example on github, I use `github@example.com` as email for commits but as they are signed with `gpg@example.com`, github marks them as *untrusted*, even though I have `gpg@example.com` as verified email on the platform, because of their *committer trust model*.

So here's the real question: According to *the state of the art* of GPG keys, what should I do? The options I've thought of so far are:

- Add `github@example.com` as an identity on my GPG key pair. But I want the key to be as generic as possible, and if I have to do this for every domain, I'll have to update my GPG key everywhere every time I get a new source.
- Like the previous one, but using a copy of the key that has, for each platform, only `gpg@example.com` and `platform@example.com` as its identity. But I have no idea if this is even possible.
- Using `gpg@example.com` as a committer, but that breaks my desire to separate email addresses.
- Any other viable option.

Probably any of these options could work, but since I'm refactoring my GPG keys and their usage, I'd like to follow *the state of the art* and not go down an unsafe or insecure way.